# File Path in Wordpress Site

Tags: php, wordpress, path

Ok, I have a dropdown menu I'm populating with a list of pdf's that are uploaded to a specific directory on my server. See "Past Meetings" on the right. http://mt-spacehosting.com/fisheries/plans/northeast-multispecies/

Using the following code, I am able to populate the list, but due to (I think) the structure of Wordpress, a 404 not found error is generated onClick. Any ideas as to why that is happening? I've searched around on various php boards, but haven't found quite what I'm looking for. Including the document root did not solve the problem.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function MM_reloadPage(init) {  //reloads the window if Nav4 resized
  if (init==true) with (navigator) {if ((appName=="Netscape")&&(parseInt(appVersion)==4)) {
    document.MM_pgW=innerWidth; document.MM_pgH=innerHeight; onresize=MM_reloadPage; }}
  else if (innerWidth!=document.MM_pgW || innerHeight!=document.MM_pgH) location.reload();
}
MM_reloadPage(true);

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++)                 x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}

function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
  if (targ == "pdfwin") {
    pdfwin = window.open(selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value, 'pdfwin', 'location=true');
  } else {

eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
  }
  if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}


function MM_jumpMenuGo(selName,targ,restore){ //v3.0
  var selObj = MM_findObj(selName); if (selObj) MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore);
}


</script>



<select name="s1" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('pdfwin',this,0)">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>

<?php 
$sub = ($_GET['dir']); 
$path = 'groundfish-meetings/'; 
$path = $path . "$sub"; 
$dh = opendir($path); 
$i=1; 

while (($file = readdir($dh)) !==   false) { 
    if($file != "." && $file != "..") { 
        if (substr($file, -4, -3) =="."){
         echo "$i. <option value='$path/$file'>$file</option>";
         } $i++; 
        } 
     } closedir($dh); 
?>
```

Comment: And you are sure `groundfish-meetings/file-name.ext` is accessible from the browser?

Comment: Well, the url gets changed on the wordpress page.  The same code functioned properly on the sample pages I placed at the root of the install: http://mt-spacehosting.com/fisheries/past-events.php

Comment: So you probably need to set a base URL for this to work!

Comment: Any hints on how to do that?  If I put a full url in the $path it doesn't work.  I looked up base url, but am not sure I understand.

Comment: Is this one of the 404s you're referring to? In that case, what is the `instance_id` for? http://mt-spacehosting.com/fisheries/ai1ec_event/summer-meet-and-greet/?instance_id=3

Comment: Hi Nicklas, if you visit http://mt-spacehosting.com/fisheries/plans/northeast-multispecies/ and select one of the files from the "Meeting Summaries" drop down menu, the popup will give you a 404 error due to the url getting changed.

For instance: http://mt-spacehosting.com/fisheries/plans/northeast-multispecies/groundfish-meetings/groundfish_jun13_ap.pdf

Should be: http://mt-spacehosting.com/fisheries/groundfish-meetings/groundfish_jun13_ap.pdf

Comment: I tried $path = "'.bloginfo('url').'/groundfish-meetings";  but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with a little help I go to this result:

Select Date

```
    <?php 
    $sub = ($_GET['dir']); 
    $path = 'groundfish-meetings/';
    $path = $path . "$sub"; 
    $dh = opendir($path); 
    $i=1; 

    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !==   false) { 
        if($file != "." && $file != "..") { 
            if (substr($file, -4, -3) =="."){
             echo "$i. <option value='" . home_url('/groundfish-meetings/' . $file) .         "'>$file</option>";
             } $i++; 
            } 
         } closedir($dh); 
    ?>
    </select>
```

Does anyone know how I would sort them by date, most recent to oldest?